# PHP converting an image to a binary file test

Tags: php, image, binary

I wanted to try to convert an image to Binary.

I found a script online but it does not work.

Could someone please advise why?

```
<?php

$image="image003.jpg";

$data = fopen ($image, 'rb');
$size=filesize ($image);
$contents= fread ($fd, $size);
fclose ($fd);

$encoded= base64_encode($contents);

echo $encoded;

 ?>
```

I have an error come up on line 8 and 9

```
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

and

```
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
```

Comment: `$fd` isn't defined here. Please show the code where `$fd` is defined.

Comment: You should use $data instead of $fd

Comment: @RichardTheobald  Thats the entire code. I found it online and thats the entire script included

Comment: I think you need to use $data and not $fd. Since you stored the file in $data

Comment: I have done the $data and it works perfect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$data` instead of `$fd`

```
$data = fopen ($image, 'rb');
$size=filesize ($image);
$contents= fread ($data, $size);
fclose ($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php.
So as you can read `fread` need a resource generate with `fopen`.

**In your case:**

```
<?php

$image = "image003.jpg"; // be careful that the path is correct

$data = fopen($image, 'rb');
$size = filesize($image);
$contents = fread($data, $size);
fclose($data);

$encoded = base64_encode($contents);

echo $encoded;

?>
```

Comment: This will not work for the same reason his original code doesn't work; `$fd` is undefined. ;-)

Comment: @RichardTheobald you right i missed the handler in fclose.. i was focus on fread, Thaks  ;)